# How to create a custom CLI tool with Typescript

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface

I just wrote a program who doing convert different `.json` file format using Typescript.

But i'm using fixed file path to read it.

```
const file = readFileSync('./name_of_file_path.json', 'utf-8'); // fix file path.
file_obj = JSON.parse(file);
// more code ...
```

I wonder can make the program become CLI tool to make the file path more flexible.

User just need at Command-prompt type:

```
converter_json [-someFlagOption] ./folder/random_json_file_path.json
```

then the program will get the user's `.json` file path like this:

```
function func_user_file_path(){ // some function like this? 
    return real_user_json_filepath;
}
var file_path_input: string; 
file_path_input = func_user_file_path() //dynamic file path (user input)
const file = file_path_input; 
file_obj = JSON.parse(file);
// more code ...
```

So my question is how to do that?

Comment: I find on Google, commander.js, Inquirer.js are the way to make a CLI tool.
But it more like using JavaScript way to do that. I wonder that using TypeScript ways.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is compiled down to JavaScript, which will be executed by NodeJS. To create a basic cli you'll create an npm package, (optionally) publish it, and then the user will install that package (npm install -g ) on their machine in order to be able to call it. There are numerous libraries that can help you with parsing command line parameters and console input/output.

Here is a quick tutorial: https://walrus.ai/blog/2019/11/typescript-cli/